# get object type and assign values accordingly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

I have an arraylist that gets **different type of values** in it, 1st value->**string**,2nd value-> **datetime**, 3rd value--> **boolean** and 4th value is **int**, how do I find thier type and assign those values accordingly, any help is appreciated:)

**here is  my Code:**

```
foreach (object obj in lstTop)
            {

              if(obj.GetType() == string)
                {do this...)
              else if(obj.GetType() == DateTime)
                {do this....}
              else if(obj.GetType() == bool)
                {do this....}
              else if(obj.GetType() == Int)
                {do this....}
            }
```

Thank you all, **my Final Code:**

```
string Subscription = "";
        DateTime issueFirst;
        DateTime issueEnd;

        foreach (object obj in lstTop)
        {
            ///Type t = obj.GetType();
            if (obj is string)
                Subscription += obj + ",";
            else if (obj is DateTime)
            {
               Subscription += Convert.ToDateTime(obj).ToShortDateString() + ",";
            }
           /// else if (t == typeof(DateTime))                
        }
    return ("User Authenticated user name: " + userName + ", Subscription: " + Subscription);
```

Comment: Add typeof() in front of the type, e.g. typeof(string), typeof(DateTime).

Comment: '2.0' by itself is a really poor tag choice.  Please pay more attention to the auto-suggest prompts for your questions in the future: correct tagging is how qualified people will find your question.

Comment: If you possibly can, get out of this situation. An array list is a terrible way to represent a four-tuple of data. Consider defining a custom class that holds these four data and use that instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach (object obj in lstTop)
        {

          if(obj is string)
            {do this.....}
          else if(obj is DateTime)
            {do this.....}
          else if(obj is bool)
            {do this.....}
          else if(obj is Int)
            {do this.....}
          else
          {
              // always have an else in case it falls through
              throw new Exception();
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

ArrayLists in .Net 2.0 are almost always the wrong way to do it.  Even if you don't know what the list will hold, you're better off using the generic `List<Object>` because that communicates to others that the list really could hold anything and isn't just a left over from a .Net 1.1 programmer.

Other than that, the `is` keyword should do what you want:

```
if (obj is string)
    // do this
else if (obj is DateTime)
    // do this
// ...
```

**Update** I know this is old, but it come up in my notices today. Reading it again, it occurs to me that another nice way to do this is via type resolution for an overloaded function:

```
void DoSomething(string value) { /* ... */ }
void DoSomething(DateTime value) { /* ... */ }

DoSomething(obj);
```

Comment: "But other than that, Mrs. Lincoln..."

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is not to use a loop since you know exactly what's in your list.

```
string   myString = (string)   lstTop[0];
DateTime myDate   = (DateTime) lstTop[1];
bool     myBool   = (bool)     lstTop[2];
int      myInt    = (int)      lstTop[3];
```

Comment: The indexes may be different though. Not always reliable.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this because the direct casts will throw runtime errors if the cast fails.

Answer (score 1):

If your list contains exactly one value of each type you can store it in a `Dictionary` instead (if using an `ArrayList` is not a specific requirement), and just retrieve the value based on the requested type:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Object> data = GetDataList();
string myString = (string)data[typeof(string)];
int myInt = (int)data[typeof(int)];
```

This will make the process of fetching the values slightly more robust since it is not depending on the values appearing in any specific order.

Example of converting the ArrayList to such a dictionary:

```
ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
data.Add(1);
data.Add("a string");
data.Add(DateTime.Now);

Dictionary<Type, Object> dataDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    dataDictionary.Add(data[i].GetType(), data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using primitive types, I'd have an abstract class that encapsulated each data type.  Then, the logic of handling that type can be embedded in the class itself.

```
foreach( MyBaseData data in lstData )
{
    data.DoTheRightThing();
}
```

In general, any code that switches on the type of an object should be considered a design smell - it may not necessarily be wrong, but it's probably a good idea to take another look at it.

While writing a class to encapsulate a simple type may feel like unnecessary work, I don't think I've ever regretted doing it.

Comment: Creating extension methods for simple types would probably be less of a hassle than encapsulating each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just some slightly cleaner code:

```
foreach (object obj in lstTop)
        {

          if(obj is string)
            {do this...)
          else if(obj is DateTime)
            {do this....}
          else if(obj is bool)
            {do this....}
          else if(obj is int)
            {do this....}
        }
```

If your array always has the same objects in the same location though, just index into the array and do direct casts.

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (object obj in lstTop)
        {

          if(obj.GetType() == typeof(string))
            {do this...)
          else if(obj.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
            {do this....}
          else if(obj.GetType() == typeof(bool))
            {do this....}
          else if(obj.GetType() == typeof(int))
            {do this....}
        }
```

The `GetType` method returns the `System.Type` of the object. Therefore you need to compare it with the another `System.Type`, which you get by using `typeof`.