# How to make/design a class which can have different type of members at runtime in C#

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I need a class which need to contain information about something which varies at runtime, for example:

```
class Info<T>
{
    public T Max { get; set; }
    public T Min { get; set; }
    public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public T Step { get; set; }
    // Some other stuff
}
```

I have to store many instances of this class in a dictionary but problem is that to use dictionary I have to declare one type e.g.

```
Dictionary<string, Info<int>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Info<int>>();
```

In this case I can't add another type of info e.g. `Info<double>`.
I want something like , I have removed generic version in below case.

```
 {"Price", new Info{Min=100,Max=1000,DefaultValue=200,Step=50}}
 {"Adv", new Info{Min=10.50,Max=500.50,DefaultValue=20.50,Step=1.5}}
 {"Answer", new Info{Min=false,Max=false,DefaultValue=false,Step=false}}
```

I can use `Dictionary<string, Object> dict = new Dictionary<string, Object>();`

but then when I get the dict item back I don't know what type is that, I need to know the type as well e.g. for `Price` it's int and for Adv it's double , how will I know it at runtime?

Actually I want to create a validator(I am using .Net Compact Framework 3.5/can not use any inbuilt system if it exists) for example If I have a class like below..

```
class Demo
{
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public float Adv { get; set; }

    public static bool Validate(Demo d)
    {
        List<string> err = new List<string>();
        // here I have to get Info about the Price
        // from dictionary, it can be any storage
        Info priceInfo = GetPriceInfo("Price");
        if (d.Price < priceInfo.Min)
        {
            d.Price = priceInfo.Min;
            err.Add("price is lower than Min Price");
        }
        if (d.Price > priceInfo.Max)
        {
            d.Price = priceInfo.Max;
            err.Add("price is above than Max Price");
        }
        // need to do similar for all kinds of properties in the class  
    }
}
```

So idea is to store validation information at one place (in dictionary or somewhere else) and then use that info at validation time, I also would like to know if I can design the above scenario in a better way ?

Maybe there is a better way to do this , any guidelines please?

Comment: What version of C# are you using?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, Info>` is slightly better but someone *will* have to know the actual type. Try to write sample code that uses this API

Comment: Why are your values going to be different types? If false is the only option, besides float, I am presuming that you are using false to signify null. I would create the object with nullable types.

Comment: Well of course you know the type in your Dictionary/Object example, just call GetType on the object, you will always get the correct underlying type. But why don't you use float/double directly? Why is it important to sometimes use int, and sometimes float? Why do you need bool anyway? I think your design is not that good. Tell us what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @dowhilefor: Pleae see the edits for use case example.

Comment: @Oded I am using .Net Compact Framework 3.5/C# 3.0

Answer (score 4):

You can use a non-generic base class:

```
public abstract class Info {
}

public class Info<T> : Info {
}
```

Now all different generic types inherit from the same base type, so you can use that in the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Info> dict = new Dictionary<string, Info>();
```

You can define properties and methods where the interface is not depending on the generic type in the base class, and implement them in the generic class. That way you can use them without specifying the generic type.

For methods where you need the type, you need specific code for each type. You can use the `is` and `as` operators to check for a type:

```
Info<int> info = dict[name] as Info<int>;
if (info != null) {
  int max = info.Max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take from Microsoft and mimic the [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface and create a `.Cast<T>`? However, somebody is going to have to know about your type unless you want to get into `dynamic` (4.0+ only) or reflection. Both of which come with a cost. Maybe you need to rethink your design?

Answer (score 0):

Keith Nicholas is right - if you want your dictionary to support multiple types, you'll need an interface, but it will need to be a [generic one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwtft8ak%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Try something like this (warning: untested code):

```
interface IInfo<T>
{
    T Max { get; set; }
    T Min { get; set; }
    T DefaultValue { get; set; }
    T Step { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<string, IInfo> dict = new Dictionary<string, IInfo>();

class AnswerInfo : IInfo<bool> { }
class PriceInfo : IInfo<int> { }
class AdvInfo : IInfo<double> { }

dict["Answer"] = new AnswerInfo() { Min = false, Max = false, DefaultValue = false, Step = false };
dict["Price"] = new PriceInfo() { Min = 100, Max = 1000, DefaultValue = 200, Step = 50 };
dict["Adv"] = new AdvInfo() { Min = 10.50, Max = 500.50, DefaultValue = 20.50 Step = 1.5 };
```

Comment: Reading my own link more carefully, it looks like I was close, but off.  You would need to make non-generic interface IInfo, and have IInfo<T> inherit from it.  That would mean the interface couldn't publicly expose settors, only gettors.  Would that still fit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Dictionary of objects (or some base class) you would have several options to get to the data (typically, involving some kind of inheritance from a common base class to work with, which has properties as outlined below).

1. Use an enum to denote the type, then you can have some kind of switch/case. (Easy to do, not very C#ish.)
2. Use something similar to a VARIANT. Variants are types that provide both information what they store and also the value stored, which can be any base type like string, int, float. (Does not really exist in C#, as you can see from the answers here [Variant Type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046622/variant-type-in-c-sharp) .)
3. You can also test the type of the object at runtime to find out what kind of an object you have, and then cast it and handle its content depending on its type. (Several ways.. might have to use reflection, for a start have a look here: [get object type and assign values accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110375/get-object-type-and-assign-values-accordingly) .)
4. You could actually also try to abstract the operation you want to do on each object in some way, and then call that function. Something like the command pattern. ([Command Pattern : How to pass parameters to a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104918/command-pattern-how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-command))

Probably many more. :)